# Linear Layout background color

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I am trying to change the background of whole screen to white. I doing it by adding by android:background="#ffffff" attribute to linerlayout. but it is not working, i dont know what i am missing ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
**android:background="#ffffff"** >
```

I also tried to this programtically , something like this 
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         LinearLayout linLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);
         linLay.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

but application throws error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

also setBackGroundColor(int) takes a @color resource , not a color integer. you declare them in values/colors.xml

Comment: thanks , but i wonder why the when i try it doing through code why it was exploding ?

Comment: possibly it was assuming a resource that didnt exist - but not sure.

Comment: I see a lot of examples using a color value, not a color resource, so I'm not sure that part of answer is correct.  The docs just say it is a "color" also, and in practice using something like 0xFF000000 does in fact set the color to black -- other values work too.  Anyway, wish the doc was clear on this as I'm currently chasing a bug that I think might be related somewhat.

Answer (score 7):

Are you please able to post the complete code necessary to replicate your problem?

This works fine for me:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
```

Comment: this line was problem android:layout_height="wrap_content"